# Possible to get username of HTTP auth logged user by Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Please, is it possible to get username of HTTP auth logged user by Google Chrome Extension? Permissions aren't problem, I can set all of them.

Thank you!

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [webRequest API](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) to look at headers for you.  Here's some sample code the parses out the base64-encoded username and password from the `Authorization` header of all HTTP requests:

```
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log(details.url, details.requestHeaders);
    for(var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
        var header = details.requestHeaders[i];
        if(header.name == "Authorization") {
            // this is my quick effort for parsing the auth value
            // formatted like "Basic [base64 of 'user:pass']"
            var b64val = header.value.split(" ")[1];
            var credArray = atob(b64val).split(":");
            var user = credArray[0];
            var pass = credArray[1];

            // now do something with user/pass
        }
    }
},
{"urls":["*://*/*"]},
["requestHeaders"]);
```

Comment: Thanks.
I've tried this but I don't see authorization header. On Google there is written:
The following headers are currently not provided to the onBeforeSendHeaders event: Authorization.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the formatting of my answer earliier, so the first line was cut off.  Now I've corrected it -- you should use the `onSendHeaders` event. You only need `onBeforeSendHeaders` if you need to *modify* headers before they are sent. To *read* from headers, you can use `onSendHeaders`.  Note: I haven't tested this, but the docs don't say anything about blocking headers from `onSendHeaders` like they do for `onBeforeSendHeaders`.

Comment: I've tried onSendHeaders too but it's the same - no Authorization header :(

Comment: Interesting.  The only solution I can think of is to use the `onAuthRequred` to have all authentication credentials pass directly through your extension (i.e., your extension would prompt for user/pass, rather than the browser).  It's poorly documented how to do this, though -- I think you'll need to use `asyncBlocking` option of `onAuthRequired` somehow.

Comment: Yeah, only solution is to prompt for credentials from extension, not browser. Sad.
Thank you for your answers!